# Receiving UDP packets in Unity Android application with broadcast

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, udp, broadcast

I am currently creating an Unity Android application (GearVR) that could receive UDP packets send with broadcast on the Wi-Fi.
Unfortunately I can't receive any packet in my application.
Here is the script which I attached to a 3d game object.

```
public class UDPSceneScript : MonoBehaviour {
Thread udpListeningThread;
Thread udpSendingThread;
public int portNumberReceive;
UdpClient receivingUdpClient;

private void initListenerThread()
{
    portNumberReceive = 5000;

    Console.WriteLine("Started on : " + portNumberReceive.ToString());
    udpListeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UdpListener));

    // Run in background
    udpListeningThread.IsBackground = true;
    udpListeningThread.Start();
}

public void UdpListener()
{
    receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(portNumberReceive);

    while (true)
    {
        //Listening 
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            //IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 5000);

            // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
            byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

            if (receiveBytes != null)
            {
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Message Received" + returnData.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Address IP Sender" + RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Port Number Sender" + RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());

                if (returnData.ToString() == "TextTest")
                {
                    //Do something if TextTest is received
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}

void Start()
{
    initListenerThread();
}
}
```

With the program SocketTest 3.0, I send "TextTest" to the address 255.255.255.255, port 5000
(I also tried by targeting directly the IP of the smartphone, it didn't work either)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran a quick test on your code and came to conclusion that your client code is fine. Replace all `Console.WriteLine` with `Debug.Log` and your will receive the data you are broadcasting. `Console.WriteLine` doesn't display anything in Unity's console.

If the problem is still there, please understand that some OS will block you from broadcasting to `255.255.255.255`. If this is the case then get the IP of the device you are broadcasting from and replace the last `octet` with `255`. Broadcast to that IP Address and that will also work just like `255.255.255.255`.

For example, if your IP is `192.168.1.13`, replace `13` with `255`. You should broadcast to `192.168.1.255` in this case.

Finally, put the code below in your client script to make sure you kill that `Thread` when you click the Stop button in the Editor or you will have many problems during development.

```
 void OnDisable()
 {
     if (udpListeningThread != null && udpListeningThread.IsAlive)
     {
         udpListeningThread.Abort();
     }

     receivingUdpClient.Close();
 }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not change anything. May be is there something to do with a Android Manifest to allow the broadcast?
Thanks for the killing-thread method.

Comment: You don't have to have change anything in the manifest. Please make sure that the firewall is not blocking you. Check in the firewall and make sure that your app is not blocked. What Unity version are you using? Does this work in the Editor?  What device are you broadcasting from?

Comment: I send UDP packets (broadcast) from computer (windows) to Smartphone running Unity App (samsung S7, android 6.0.1), they are connected to the same wi-fi
I use Unity 5.3.5p8 Personal
When I test it with "Game" tab, it works, I receive the packet.
Should i disable the firewall on windows?

Comment: First of all, download Unity 5.4 if possible. They fixed many network bugs. Simply changing `Console.WriteLine` with `Debug.Log` worked on my side. You still did not answer my question. Does that code work in the Editor? Did you read the whole answer? Did you try the Ip 192.168.1.255 stuff I wrote in my answer? You are not suppose to disable firewall. You are suppose to make it allow some apps to receive traffic from the netowork. You can easily google how to do this

Comment: Allright, I will try with unity 5.4. 
I change console.writeline -> debug.log, this allow me to see that it works in the editor, if by this you mean the unity Game tab.
I also tried the IP 192.168.1.255, it doesnt change anything as I said.

Comment: There is no guarantee that your ip is 192.168.1.xx, You have to find your own ip and replace the last octet with 255. You can google how to find your own ip in your computer. Also, you haven't said if it is working in the Editor or not.  Let me know when you try this in Unity 5.4

Comment: Since this just happened to me I would like to point out that the broadcast section of the address is anything the mask exposes, not the last three digits.  My mask is 255.255.254.0 and my ip address is 192.168.4.124 so I have to broadcast to 192.168.5.255.  Every bit exposed must be set to 1.
In practice this works out to the largest number you can set in your address range.